# S3 bucket folder tree visualization

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, graph-visualization

Can any one suggest a node package to visualize s3 bucket contents in a tree.I'm currently using jsTree package on handling this but there's hell of a rework to create the json required by the js package.Is there any library to handle the visualization of s3 bucket easily.Can some one help